# ZF2 Routing Confusion

Tags: routes, zend-framework2, hostname

I am sure the answer to this is obvious, but it is eluding me right now.  I have the following code in my module.config.php

```
'subdomain' => array(
    'type' => 'Hostname',
    'options'=> array(
        'route' => ':subdomain.mydomain.com',
        'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
            'action'    => 'foo',
        ),
    ),
    'child_routes' => array(
        'withcontroller' => array(
            'type' => 'Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '[/:controller/:action]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                ),
                'defaults' => array(),
             ),
         ),
```

If I remove the `child_routes, test.mydomain.com` is matched  no problem.  When I add the `child_routes` section, `test.mydomain.com/Index/foo` is matched, but `test.mydomain.com` is not matched.  I thought that the square parentheses around `/:controller/:action` would make those parameters optional.  What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: Have you registered the controller in module.php invokables?

Comment: Okay, found the solution, not sure why, but moving the slash from :controller outside the paran's makes everything work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, found the solution, not sure why, but moving the slash from :controller outside the paran's makes everything work fine.